# How to setup Disaster recovery for GridDB?

Tags: griddb

I know the backup and restore process of GridDB which is specified [here](https://www.toshiba-sol.co.jp/en/pro/griddb/docs-en/v4_0_3/GridDB_TechnicalReference.html), however, I would like to know how to setup Disaster Recovery (To a different site) using methods such as log shipping, Distributed Clustering, etc.